# Laravel 9 pass variable from route to controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**My problem:**
I am currently trying to refactor some of my controllers. Doing so I found these two routes:

```
Route::get('/events', [EventsController::class, 'eventsList'])->name('event-list');
Route::get('/courses', [EventsController::class, 'allCoursesList'])->name('all-events');
```

they show different filter options in the frontend.

**What I want to do:**

Example Code:

```
Route::get('/courses', [
    'all' => 1,
    EventsController::class, 'courseList'
])->name('all-events');
```

so having the ability to pass a variable, in this case `all` to my controller. `EventsController`  So I can check with `if` in my controller and handle these routes differently with only one function instead of two.

With the current solutions on StackOverflow, users are using:

```
'uses'=>'myController@index'
```

now if I try it like this:

```
Route::get('/courses', [
    'all' => 1,
    'uses' => 'EventsController@CourseList'
])->name('all-events');
```

I get the following error:

```
Target class [EventsController] does not exist.
```

**Question:** 
What is the current, correct way, to pass a variable to a controller, from a route. In Laravel 9 and 10.

Comment: Not sure but I think you have to use the FQCN (e.g. `\App\Http\Controllers\EventsController@Courselist`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary data to the route as a parameter using the `defaults` method of `Route`:

```
Route::get('courses', [EventsController::class, 'list'])
    ->name('all-events')
    ->defaults('all', 1);

Route::get('events', [EventsController::class, 'list'])
    ->name('event-list');


public function list(Request $request, $all = 0)
{
    ...
}
```

There are also other ways of using the Route to pass data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters) to pass variable from route to controller.

```
// web.php
Route::get('/events/{all}', [EventsController::class, 'eventsList'])->name('event-list');
```

then in your controller you can access the variables

```
   public function eventsList(Request $request,$all){

         if($all==1){
        //your logic for handling the condition when $all =1
      }

        // the remaining condition
    }
```

if you have multiple parameters you can pass them like so, you can use `?` for optional parameter.

```
// web.php
Route::get('/courses/{param_one}/{param_two?}', [EventsController::class, 'allCoursesList'])->name('all-events');
```

then in your controller you can access the variables

```
    public function allCoursesList(Request $request,$paramOne,$paramTwo){

        return $paramOne.' '.$paramTwo;
    }
```

to access the query parameter

```
// web.php
Route::get('/evets', [EventsController::class, 'allCoursesList'])->name('all-events');
```

if the route were `/events?timeframe=0&category=1` you can access the query parameter like so

```
    public function allCoursesList(Request $request,$paramOne,$paramTwo){
$timeframe= $request->query('timeframe');
// do this for all the query parameters
       
    }
```

Comment: While this could make sense. I dont think that it could work in my case, maybe you have another idea. The URL Parameters are e.g. `/events?timeframe=0&category=1`

Comment: @NiftyMatrix the answer is updated to suite your need

Answer (score 1):

Laravel versions 8 and above [do not automatically apply namespace prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates). This means that when passing the class name as a string, you need to use the fully qualified class name (FQCN).

For example:

```php
Route::get('/courses', [
    'all' => 1,
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\EventsController@CourseList'
])->name('all-events');
```

If it makes sense for your use case, you could also use URL parameters. For example, if your `Course` models belong to a `Category` model, you might do something like this:

```
Route::get('/courses/{category}', [EventsController::class, 'allCourseList');
```

Then in your countroller, you define the `allCoursesList` function like so:

```
public function allCoursesList(Category $category)
{
    // ... do something with $category which is an instance of the Category model.
}
```